# Ruby on Rails - block in ffi_lib: Could not open library 'libcurl'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows-7

I'm getting the error in the link below.  - block in ffi_lib: Could not open library 'libcurl'

Rails Version: 3.2.11
Ruby Version: 1.9.3p125
Operating System: Windows 7

[error](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/824/fmla.jpg/)

Comment: So? Did you install libcurl?

Comment: As per Yevgeniy, I think 'libcurl' is not installed. You should try to install libcurl first from here : http://curl.haxx.se/mail/lib-2010-03/0152.html. and then run.

Comment: It still says I'm missing the libcurl file or it is corrupted.  :(